# The integrals from $1$ to $\infty$ for $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have two integrals:

$$
A=\int\limits_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x}dx\,,
B=\int\limits_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^2}dx
$$

Calculus says that A is an improper integral as it diverges, but the B converges and is $1$, because $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is faster near $y=0$ than $\dfrac{1}{x}$.

I don't understand the reason behind this. So I looked for another way to put down my problem. Multiple sources define that:

$$
\frac{1}{\infty} = \frac{1}{\infty^2}
$$

What is the reason that the integral of $\dfrac{1}{x}$ is divergent and $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is convergent? In the end they both reach $\dfrac{1}{\infty}$ (or $\dfrac{1}{\infty^2}$ which is $\dfrac{1}{\infty}$).

Comment: They're *both* improper (Riemann) integrals. $A$ is a divergent improper Riemann integral and $B$ is a convergent one. The Riemann integral is only defined for (certain) bounded functions on bounded intervals. They're called improper because they're limits (in a suitable sense) as the (in this case) upper integration boundary "goes to infinity".

Comment: What happens *at* $\infty$ doesn't matter. It's what happens "near" $\infty$ that matters: i.e. how the function behaves for large (finite) real values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer has nothing to do with '$\infty$ calculus'. Calculate the finite integral first, and take limits.

$\int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt = \ln x$, $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t^2} dt = 1-\frac{1}{x}$.

$A = \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln x = \infty$, $B =\lim_{x \to \infty} 1-\frac{1}{x} = 1$.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x}dx & = & \lim_{ \varepsilon \rightarrow \infty }   \int\limits_1^\varepsilon \dfrac{1}{x}dx 
& = & \lim_{ \varepsilon \rightarrow \infty } \log \varepsilon = \infty
\end{eqnarray}
While
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^2}dx & =& \lim_{ \varepsilon \rightarrow \infty } \Bigr(-\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon } +1 \Bigl) = 1
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: You likely mean $\epsilon \to \infty$, not $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [Cauchy integral test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegralTest.html) which tells us that we can compare an infinite sum with a corresponding integral and vice versa under certain circumstances (see the [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegralTest.html)). Because
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{x}}$$
diverges so does the integral and since
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{x^2}}}}$$
converges so does the integral. By the way, infinity is not a number. Saying $\infty^2$ is the same as saying $\text{blue}^2$ -- it does not mean anything, so you cannot look at these integral as fractions with $\infty$ as a denominator.

Comment: (assuming the function $f$ is non-negative, decreasing, and continuous)

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, hence the link. I did not want to write it all out.

Comment: I know it is a label, but as it is infinite, there is nothing more, so why would $\infty^2$ not be $\infty$? And is Wolfram|Alpha wrong? [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Finfinity+%3D+1%2Finfinity%5E2)

Comment: @glebovg: It's worth mentioning something conditional in your statement, then. e.g. "... which tells us **when** we can compare ..." or "... which tells us that we can compare ... if certain properties are met ..." or something.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks.

Comment: @Jarvix It is a word. $\infty$ is a concept. For example taking the limit as something approached infinity is not the same as evaluating it at infinity. Not to mention, [some infinities are bigger than others](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CantorDiagonalMethod.html).

Answer (score 0):

Improper integrals, such as $A$ and $B$ are *defined* as limits:
$$A= \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}dx= \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_1^R \frac{1}{x}dx$$
and 
$$B= \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}dx= \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_1^R \frac{1}{x^2}dx$$
If you carry out the details you'll get $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \ln R$$ which goes to $\infty$ and $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{R}$$ which converges.